# 'new Date()' gets a wrong timezone from headless chrome in linux docker image

Tags: google-chrome, docker, timezone, headless

I have a docker image with linux, and there is a headless chrome service. When I use "new Date()" in my html, it get a time "Sat Dec 29 2018 02:45:24 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)", it's wrong. The docker time is 'Sat, 29 Dec 2018 17:24:27 +0800', it's right.

And my time zone is 'CST' (China standard Time), as similar as 'CST'(Central Standard Time). Dose that matter?...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbX1I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, containers are created in `UTC` timezone by default. How to make it correspond to your host's OS - depends on the type of guest OS. For `Debian` I simply set

**Dockerfile**

```
....
ENV TZ=Europe/Moscow   # or whatever is you one
....
```

Comment: It works!  I set 'etc/localtime' of OS but did not set Dockerfile. Thank you a lot!